# Load balancing SQL reads while batch-processing?

Tags: sql, transactions, load-balancing, batch-processing

Given an SQL table with timestamped records. Every once in a while an application `App0` does something like `foreach record in since(certainTimestamp) do process(record); commitOffset(record.timestamp)`, i.e. periodically it consumes a batch of "fresh" data, processes it sequentially and commits success after each record and then just sleeps for reasonable time (to accumulate yet another batch). That works perfect with single instance.. however how to load balance multiple ones?

In exactly the same environment `App0` and `App1` **concurrently** competite for the fresh data. The idea is that ready query executed by the `App0` **must not** overlay with the same read query executed by the `App1` - such that they never try to process the same item. In other words, I need SQL-based guarantees that concurrent read queries return different data. Is that even possible?

P.S. Postgres is preferred option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem description is rather vague on what **App1** should do while **App0** is processing the previously selected records.
In this answer, I make the following assumptions:

- all **Apps** somehow know what the last `certainTimestamp` is and it is the same for all **Apps** whenever they start a DB query.
- while **App0** is processing, say the 10 records it found when it started working, new records come in. That means, the pile of new records with respect to `certainTimestamp` grows.
- when **App1** (or any further *App*) starts, the should process only those new records with respect to `certainTimestamp` that are not yet being handled by other *Apps*.
- yet, if on **App** fails/crashes, the unfinished records should be picked the next time another **App** runs.

This can be achieved by *locking* records in many SQL databases.

One way to go about this is to use

```
 SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

This statement, in combination with the range-selection `since(certainTimestamp)` selects and locks all records matching the condition and not being locked currently.
Whenever a new **App** instance runs this query, it only gets "what's left" to do and can work on that.

This solves the problem of **"overlay"** or working on the same data.

What's left is then the definition and update of the `certainTimestamp`.
In order to keep this answer short, I don't go into that here and just leave the pointer to the OP that this needs to be thought through properly to avoid situations where e.g. a single record that cannot be processed for some reason keeps the `certainTimestamp` at a permanent minimum.